# Echo command containing both double and single quotes

Tags: bash

I have this command

```
cp $(ldd MyApp.out | awk '{print $3}' | sed -E '/^$/d') lib/
```

and at some point, I want to `echo` it into a file but a naive approach `echo command_above` doesn't work.

If I put the command into single quotes, then `$3` expands to whitespace.
Is it possible to print that command char-by-char as it is after `echo` command without any expansion and substitution?

Comment: side note: you don't need both awk and sed to remove empty lines, just `awk '$3!=""{print $3}'`.

Comment: @thanasisp nice note, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The common approach is to use the `<<` operator to read until some delimiter:

```sh
# "cat" just prints what it reads 
cat << 'EOF' > output_file
cp $(ldd MyApp.out | awk '{print $3}' | sed -E '/^$/d') lib/
EOF
```

Comment: It's important to quote `EOF` as `'EOF'` to disable special characters. If you write `EOF` the dollar signs will be expanded the same as if using double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use xargs to pass file names list to cp

```sh
ldd MyApp.out | awk '$3!=""{print $3}' | xargs -d'\n' -I{} cp {} lib/
```

Answer (score 0):

For debugging and logging purposes you can use `set -x` or `set -v`:

```
set -v  # dump commands below
cp $(ldd MyApp.out | awk '{print $3}' | sed -E '/^$/d') lib/
set +v  # stop dumping
```